# C#. Разжатие файла при помощи GZip в многопоточной среде

Tags: c#, gzip

Пытаюсь разобраться как написать процесс сжатия и разжатия при помощи GZip в многопоточной среде.

При разжатии файла в многопоточной среде выдает постоянно следующие ошибки: `StackOverFlow`, `System.OutOfMemory`.

В режиме отладки на строках:

```
blockLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(lengthBuffer, 4);
```

и

```
_dataSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(compressedData[i], blockLength - 4)
```

во втором потоке присваиваются космические переменные, которые и ведут к фатальным ошибкам. Пробовал ставить 4 байта, всячески "игрался", пытаясь реализовать по-разному. Итог один. Прошу помощи!. Код ниже.

```
public abstract class GZip
    {
        protected static bool _cancelled = false;
        protected static bool _success = false;
        protected string sourceFile, destinationFile;
        protected static int _threads = Environment.ProcessorCount;
        protected const int buffer_size = 1024 * 1024;

        protected static int blockSize = 10000000;
        protected static byte[][] lastBuffer = new byte[_threads][];
        protected static byte[][] compressedData = new byte[_threads][];


        public GZip(string input, string output)
        {
            this.sourceFile = input;
            this.destinationFile = output;
        }

        public int CallBackResult()
        {
            if (!_cancelled && _success)
                return 0;
            return 1;
        }

        public void Cancel()
        {
            _cancelled = true;
        }

        public abstract void Launch();
    }

    class Decompressor : GZip
    {
        public Decompressor(string input, string output) : base(input, output)
        {


        }
        public override void Launch()
        {
            Console.Write("Decompressing");
            try
            {
                using (FileStream _compressedFile = new FileStream(sourceFile, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    using (FileStream _decompressedFile = new FileStream(sourceFile.Remove(sourceFile.Length - 3), FileMode.Append))
                    {
                        int blockLength;
                        int _dataSize;
                        byte[] lengthBuffer = new byte[8];
                        Thread[] tPool = new Thread[_threads];

                        while (_compressedFile.Position < _compressedFile.Length)
                        {

                            for (int i = 0; (i < _threads) && (_compressedFile.Position < _compressedFile.Length); i++)
                            {
                                Console.Write(".");

                                _compressedFile.Read(lengthBuffer, 0, lengthBuffer.Length);
                                blockLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(lengthBuffer, 4);
                                compressedData[i] = new byte[blockLength];
                                lengthBuffer.CopyTo(compressedData[i], 0);

                                _compressedFile.Read(compressedData[i], 8, blockLength - 8);
                                _dataSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(compressedData[i], blockLength - 4);
                                lastBuffer[i] = new byte[_dataSize];



                                tPool[i] = new Thread(Decompress);
                                tPool[i].Start(i);
                            }

                            for (int i = 0; (i < _threads) && (tPool[i] != null);)
                            {
                                if (tPool[i].ThreadState == ThreadState.Stopped)
                                {
                                    _decompressedFile.Write(lastBuffer[i], 0, lastBuffer[i].Length);
                                    i++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error is occured!\n Method: {0}\n Error description {1}", ex.TargetSite, ex.Message);
                _cancelled = true;
            }
        }

        public static void Decompress(object i)
        {
            using (MemoryStream _memoryStream = new MemoryStream(compressedData[(int)i]))
            {
                using (GZipStream cs = new GZipStream(_memoryStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                {
                    cs.Read(lastBuffer[(int)i], 0, lastBuffer[(int)i].Length);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Метка языка программирования отсутствует на вопросе. Поставьте, больше просмотров будет. НАМНОГО ;)

Comment: Зависит от  protected static int _threads = Environment.ProcessorCount;

В моем случае это 2. Но, однако, на втором потоке выбивает вышеописанные ошибки.

На маленьких файлах программа "успешно завершается", только почему то все происходит в одном потоке, записывается около 16 000 байт и на этом все завершается.

Comment: Попробуйте добавьте в общие для thread-ов переменные метку **volatile**, для compressedData и других учасников

Comment: Не помогло. Вот подробный пример. Длина сжатого файла составляет 87952607 Первый поток: blockLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(lengthBuffer, 4); -в этой строке переменной приписывается 9284445  _dataSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(compressedData[i], blockLength - 4); - а в этой 520132758  Второй поток: blockLength уже равна 67145198, а _dataSize 1236379320 , что приводит к ошибке

Comment: Откройте для себя метод [`Thread.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.thread.join(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Ваш код неявно предполагает, что `GZipStream`'у можно скормить случайный фрагмент сжатого файла, и он его сможет разжать.

Это не так. В сжатом файле есть служебная информация, которую `GZipStream` не может найти, если ему достаётся лишь кусок файла.

Судя по всему, случайные данные воспринимаются кодом как управляющая информация, что и приводит к проблемам.

---

[Формат gzip](http://www.zlib.org/rfc-gzip.html#file-format) состоит из нескольких, кладущихся впритык кусков. Какие бы ни были размеры каждого куска, архиватор распаковывает куски один за одним. В начале каждого куска есть десятибайтный заголовок, содержащий информацию о куске. Но в этом заголовке нет информации о том, какого размера упакованные данные. За заголовком следует информация, упакованная [алгоритмом Deflate](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1951), после которой — контрольная сумма и размер распакованных данных.

Поэтому склеивать файл из кусков легко, просто можно укладывать их один за другим. А вот для того, чтобы разбить файл на правильные куски, требуется узнать границы куска. Я покамест не вижу, как сделать это, не осуществляя по сути распаковку Deflate.

Ваш код по сути берёт случайные границы кусков, поэтому интерпретировать данные на границе куска как длину нельзя.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Не могли бы вы в кратце описать как это можно разрешить?

Comment: @Mikezar: Вопрос в том, как вы паковали файл. Это нормальный gzip-архив? Или он был упакован каким-то хитрым образом?

Comment: Нормальный. Перед компрессией разбивается на равные порции, поочередно сжимается, затем записываются в файл. Получаемый архив можно запросто распокавать стандартным Windows'ским архиватором Winrar или Zip. Все данные целы.

Comment: @Mikezar: Интересно. А можно пример такого архива выложить? (Желательно, небольшой.) Ещё вопрос — при распаковке Winrar'ом вы получаете назад точно **все** данные, или только первый кусок? Это важно.

Comment: Пример архива: http://my-files.ru/ivu573
Если я правильно понял вопрос...  то все.

Comment: @Mikezar: Ага, я понял. Формат gzip позволяет несколько кусков впритык. Но нужен дополнительный анализ, чтобы понять, где же эти куски. Сейчас напишу, подождите.

Comment: @VladD вот только длина упакованного куска нигде не хранится :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Угу :-( Как раз начал писать парсер формата, когда вдруг понял, что не выйдет. Жалко. Поищу ещё, вдруг найду :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Может, в формате deflate есть?

Comment: @Mikezar: Всё хуже :-( Обновил ответ.

Comment: Как было уже сказано, распаковка производится только линейно т.к в gzip нет FAT как такового где будет хранится информация обо всех блоках сразу - в этом формате это записано линейно. Посмотрите тут - http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread927080.html

Comment: @DanielProtopopov: Ну, как-то ж WinRAR показывает размер без распаковки? Значит, покопавшись в формате Deflate, можно таки достать нужную информацию. В худшем случае — упрощённая распаковка вручную :-)

Comment: Вот и я думал - как? Прихожу к выводу что он вероятно читает ВЕСЬ файл сразу и потом показывает что внутри архива. Хотя вот что - если паковать кусок КАК ФАЙЛ внутри архива, то тогда он должен показывать его в FAT у себя...?

Answer (score 2):

После долгих мучений я все же разобрался как это реализовать по-человечески. Посмотреть код можно в моем профиле на Git: https://github.com/Mikezar/GZip

Answer (score 0):

Вот моя реализация , параллелится хорошо, работает довольно шустро.
Так же добавил возможность архивировать папки, описание структуры выложу позже, кому интересно , юзайте, критикуйте)
https://github.com/githihfuhg/ParallelArchiver

Comment: _описание структуры выложу позже_ - пожалуйста не затягивайте с этим, после проверки другими участниками, ваше сообщение может быть удалено как ответ содержащий только ссылку.